# Is Google Drive API broken? I can't make it to send email notification

Tags: php, google-drive-api

today i have got a problem with receiving a notification email after creating a new file to Google Drive through the API and sharing it with another email. I was using "sendNotificationEmail" => true and it was working for 1+ year. Today it's not working and i couldn't find anything about that. I am using a service account for that. I tried to create a file manually and share it with the same email i used through the API and it worked ( I received an email notification on the chosen email address ). Here is a code sample.

```
$share_email = "foo@example.com";
$filename = "This is a title";
$content = "This is a content";

$credentialsFile = PATH_TO_JSON;
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('gdocs');
$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFile);
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
]);
$gDrive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($filename);
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');
$file = $gDrive->files->create($file, [
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'text/plain'
]);

$permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permission->setType('user');
$permission->setRole('writer');
$permission->setEmailAddress($share_email);
$gDrive->permissions->create($file->getId(), $permission, array(
    'fields' => 'id',
    'sendNotificationEmail' => true
));
```

**Result**: foo@example.com gets the shared file, but doesn't receive any email.

**Expected result**: foo@example.com receives email as well as the shared file.

Is there anyone experiencing the same problem or anyone knowing a fix about that ?

P.S. I am using v3 of the API.

P.S.2 I tried with oAuth2 and it's working great ( the email i am sharing a file with is receiving a notification ).. However i would like to keep using it with a service account if possible.

Comment: Hi ! I have tried to reproduce your issue with a normal account and unfortunately I could not encounter this issue as everything was working correctly. Is this that happens to you exclusively when you use a service account for making the request? Does this service account have domain wide delegation?

Comment: Hello, no - the service account doesn't have domain wide delegation. As i mentioned in P.S.2 I tried with oAuth using a normal account and everything is working fine. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue described here. Using the Drive v3 API, with the official google java client, the email notifications stopped working sometime around 5/15 for us. We made no changes to our code. Manually creating and sharing files to the recipient email successfully sends notifications.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide domain wide delegation to your service account and test it to see if you encounter any change and let me know? **Domain wide delegation is needed to be able to use oAuth2 with your service account**. For iformation about how to do this, [check the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). Thanks !

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am experimenting the same problem with python client and Drive v3 API while authenticating with a service account, it used to work fine until yesterday.

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Hey, i didn't find / stopped searching for solution on this topic.